# Dart DateTime to PHP's DateTime::ATOM String conversion

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart, converters

I need to send a DateTime string from a dart application to a backend that accepts dates in PHP's DateTime::ATOM format (example: 2005-08-15T15:52:01+00:00). The format is described as "Y-m-d\TH:i:sP", where P is:

> Difference to Greenwich time (GMT) with colon between hours and minutes e.g. +02:00.

So far I wasn't able to come up with a good solution on how to generate DateTime strings in the required format from dart.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();

print(now); // Output: 2020-03-02 17:04:08.587613
print(now.toIso8601String()); // Output: 2020-03-02T17:04:08.587613
print(now.toUtc().toIso8601String()); // Output: 2020-03-02T16:04:08.587613Z
print(DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss').format(now)); // Output: 2020-03-02T17:04:08
```

Is there maybe an easy whay that I haven't seen so far or someone even has an idea on how to write a simple converter function for that?

Cheers

Comment: `DateFormat('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss+00:00')`

Comment: @Kahou it produces the correct format, I've gotten so far above. What confused me was the "Difference to Greenwich time (GMT)" thing, but actually if the formatted date is in UTC it should probably be okay to always use +00:00. So answer would probably be: `DateFormat('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss+00:00').format(DateTime.now().toUtc())`

Comment: Dart doesn't support time zones. You can try : https://pub.dev/packages?q=timezone

Comment: @Kahou I guess when hardcoding +00:00 it should be: `DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss+00:00').format(now.toUtc());`